# c# I want to know if the first 3 characters in a string is letter?

Tags: c#, string, numbers, character

I'm developing a license plate number recognition system. The plate numbers in our county has a string length of 6-7. The first 2 or 3 character are  letters and the rest are numbers.

I want to check when my system detect a object and recognize it then if the output has the format of 3 letters and followed by numbers.

Comment: Slightly improved language. Also, where is your current code? What attempts have you made so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var input = "abc123";
var result = input.Take(3).All(char.IsLetter);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help a lot. I suggest that you also do validation not to allow charactors like *&&$%$^@)&(& as this will break your application. Good Luck!

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Comment: okay sir thanks a lot, also for the validation tip :) i almost forgot that :)